# Unable to create multi-site sub-directory in drupal

Tags: multi-sites

I need help creating multi-site sub-directory in drupal. I have done all setting changes in localhost windows wamp server don't know what is missing.

let say, mysite is a main site and project1, project2 sub directory. Sharing same code base but different database.

In hosts file i have done the changes like this.

127.0.0.1 project1
127.0.0.1 project2

created project1 and project2 folder under sites folder and added setting files

DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mysite"
     ServerName project1

Its working fine for http:// localhost/mysite/ and http:// project1/,http:// project2.

But I want to show it in sub-directory like http:// localhost/mysite/project1 or http:// localhost/mysite/project2.

I have tried with doing Apache alias as well and it is point to relevant DB also but when I clicked any links from http:// localhost/mysite/project1 it will show an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to alter the hosts file if you don't care about serving on more than one address. If you have an Apache vhost entry for 127.0.0.1/localhost (you will by default, and I think Apache will add a hosts entry for 127.0.0.1) then if you have a public_html dir at `mysite` you can just dump any number of Drupal installs under that dir.

E.g. 
`/home/niklp/public_html/index.html <- get this working, then you can do:
/home/niklp/public_html/drupal1
...
/home/niklp/public_html/drupalx`

Sorry if this is a little vague but it's not a Drupal issue, it's an Apache config thing that should be easily resolved.

Edit: you will have a billion less issues if you get off windows and onto linux even for basic setups.